# Is "Personality of Godhead" a Hindu term?

Tags: gods

What is a Godhead as opposed to God?

Can it be both a personality and impersonal?

Comment: If you are worried about "Supreme personality of Godhead" or something like that often found in ISckon translations of Puranas, then that is just the translation of the word **Bhagavan**.. and Bhagavan is definitely a Hindu term.. For example, in the entire Vedas (Samhitas) Lord Rudra is the only deity who is mentioned as Bhagavan (See Rudram).

Comment: Really? @rickross  Rudra alone is called Bhagavan in the Samhitas of the 4 Vedas?  He is of course dragged through a lot in the Brahmanas.

Comment: Yes to my knowledge he is the only one mentioned as Bhagavan in the entire Vedas (Samhitas)